# log4cxx/logger.h or libcql/cql.hpp fatal error while doing make -j4

Tags: compiling, libraries

I am running `make -j4` and I am getting below exception...

```
userName@phx5qa01c-4e23:~/build$ make -j4
[  1%] [  2%] Building CXX object nda/common/loadtest/CMakeFiles/loadtester.dir/LoadTester.cc.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/include/libcql/lib/libcql.so', needed by `nda/common/client/client'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Building CXX object nda/unittest/common/CMakeFiles/TestRunner.dir/TestRunner.cc.o
[  3%] Building CXX object nda/common/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/main.cc.o
[  4%] Building CXX object nda/common/CMakeFiles/ndacommon.dir/category_map/CategoryMap.cc.o
In file included from /home/userName/MPL/nda/common/client/main.cc:1:
/home/userName/MPL/nda/common/client/be_cassandra_util.hh:5: fatal error: libcql/cql.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nda/common/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/main.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nda/common/client/CMakeFiles/client.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  5%] Building CXX object nda/common/CMakeFiles/ndacommon.dir/curl_handler/CurlHandler.cc.o
/home/userName/MPL/nda/common/curl_handler/CurlHandler.cc:12: fatal error: log4cxx/logger.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nda/common/CMakeFiles/ndacommon.dir/curl_handler/CurlHandler.cc.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/userName/MPL/nda/unittest/common/TestRunner.cc:8: fatal error: log4cxx/logger.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nda/unittest/common/CMakeFiles/TestRunner.dir/TestRunner.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nda/unittest/common/CMakeFiles/TestRunner.dir/all] Error 2
/home/userName/MPL/nda/common/category_map/CategoryMap.cc:11: fatal error: log4cxx/logger.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nda/common/CMakeFiles/ndacommon.dir/category_map/CategoryMap.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nda/common/CMakeFiles/ndacommon.dir/all] Error 2
Linking CXX executable loadtester
[  5%] Built target loadtester
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Below is the exception, I always get -

`fatal error: libcql/cql.hpp: No such file or directory`

`fatal error: log4cxx/logger.h: No such file or directory`

I am not sure what should I do to fix these exceptions?

I guess, I might need to add the libraries for these... But I am not sure how should I add these libraries and where to put it then so that while compiling it works fine..

Comment: Does it work with a plain `make` (no `-j` option)? If it does, it means that the makefiles are not designed for parallel compilation.

Comment: No it doesn't work with simple make as well.. It gives me the same error... `fatal error: log4cxx/logger.h: No such file or directory`